# Can fluentd replace rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog, fluentd

Can fluentd replace rsyslog to centralize logs?

I want to centralize my logs (comming from syslog on 514 UDP port) in files like <host>.log.

Can fluentd do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve records via the syslog protocol on UDP or TCP,
you can use syslog input plugin for fluentd.

[in_syslog](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_syslog) is included in Fluentd’s core, so you probably already have it.